# Error: "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" while using cron job

Tags: git, ssh, cron, ssh-keys

I've got a cron job that has been running for over a year now that adds files to a git without an issue. For some reason, I have started to notice the job is failing with the following error.

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Is there some issue with cron that cron won't have access to the home dir of the ssh key causing it to fail?  I don't think the directory is encrypted.

```
$ ls /home/cron/.ecryptfs
ls: cannot access '/home/cron/.ecryptfs': No such file or directory
```

Every-time I login to the server through SSH and run the script I have no issues getting it to push. Any idea what could be going wrong here or what I can do to trouble shoot this issue?

Comment: Add to cronjob, for debug purposes `log` and add to ssh command more verbose with `-vvv`

Comment: well, I'm not directly using ssh, using git, is there a similar command for git?

Comment: message is `/home/cron/.ecryptf`**No such file or directory** IMHO there're a mistake on path.

Answer (score -1):

Check if one of the reasons from  "[this article](https://www.psychz.net/client/question/en/sshexchangeidentification-connection-closed-by-remote-host.html)" applies.

I would check if a normal SSH session generates some noise when login (meaning the remote user `.bashrc`/`.profile` would print some lines instead of being silent)

And I would double check the cron command does use the right private key.